# How to cast to <CustomType> result of useFetch in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to cast result of useFetch to List

```
async getAllFiscalYear(): Promise<CustomType>[]> {
        let customTypeList: CustomType[] = [];
        customTypeList= await useFetch('/api/list') as CustomType[];
        return CustomTypeList;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async getAllFiscalYear(): Promise<CustomType>[]> {
        const { data } = await useFetch<{ data: CustomType[] }>('/api/list');
        return data;
    };
```